# Semantic search - retrieve sentences from a bunch of text files that closely matches the passed in search phrase

Tags: python, elasticsearch, search, nltk, semantics

I have a bunch of text files. My application requirement is to search for sentences (or paragraphs) which matches semantically to the search phrase I pass.

e.g.: Let us say there is a sentence "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog".

I would like the following search phrases to search through my text files and list the above sentence (sometimes along with the previous and the next sentence so as to show the context)

- quick fox
- fox jump over dog
- bron fox (note the spelling mistake here)

(This is typically what they say is used in the patent search sites to identify patents based on the search phrase - semantic search)

For implementation - I looked up the internet and this is what I found:

1. Use sentence tokenizer from the nltk python library to break up text files into sentences:

> ```
> from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize 
> f = open("fileName")
> mytext = f.readline()
> sent_tokenize(mytext)
> ```

2. Need an equivalent of elastic search's match feature where passing the search phrases as above would actually find the sentence I am looking for.

[image]

Please suggest me a simple way of achieving both 1 and 2 using some library. This application just runs locally on my machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Dependencies:

```
pip install autocorrect
```

## Code (search.py) :

```
from autocorrect import spell
def lcs(X, Y):
    mat = []
    for i in range(0,len(X)):
        row = []
        for j in range(0,len(Y)):
            if X[i] == Y[j]:
                if i == 0 or j == 0:
                    row.append(1)
                else:
                    val = 1 + int( mat[i-1][j-1] )
                    row.append(val)
            else:
                row.append(0)
        mat.append(row)
    new_mat = []
    for r in  mat:
        r.sort()
        r.reverse()
        new_mat.append(r)
    lcs = 0
    for r in new_mat:
        if lcs < r[0]:
            lcs = r[0]
    return lcs
def spellCorrect(string):
    words = string.split(" ")
    correctWords = []
    for i in words:
        correctWords.append(spell(i))
    return " ".join(correctWords)
def semanticSearch(searchString, searchSentencesList):
    result = None
    searchString = spellCorrect(searchString)
    bestScore = 0
    for i in searchSentencesList:
        score = lcs(searchString, i)
        if score > bestScore:
            bestScore = score
            result = i
    return result


result = semanticSearch("fox jump over dog", ["The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog", "This is one more string which contains fox bron"])
print result
```

Comment: Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this definitely helps. Let us say I am searching something from my notes made up of non-english words - result = semanticSearch("bahv", ["baloon", "Bhavs grape juice 8000087", "broom stick", "black swan"]) - in this I am expecting it to return the second sentence whereas it returns baloon. This works in elasticsearch (as per my understanding). Do you think we can get this working ?

Comment: Yes, because it is not using any semantics... it's purely based on syntactic features... If you want it to search based on some semantic features ... go look through STSAPP.py and see the features which are defined as functions in this repo https://github.com/TilakPutta/STS

Refer this paper for more information http://troindia.in/journal/ijcesr/vol4iss8part3/75-79.pdf

Comment: I have accepted your answer, in case you can solve this - result = semanticSearch("bahv", ["baloon", "Bhavs grape juice 8000087", "broom stick", "black swan"]) - please let me know...